# commands not working when event is over it

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I read how `on_message` events need to have `await bot.process_commands(message)` at the end so that it can run commands after but it doesn't work for me. Do you have any clue why it doesn't work?

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message): 
    print(message.author.id)
    if message.author.id == <user_id>:
        await message.add_reaction("❤️")
    else:  
        return
        await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `return` statement before processing the commands, it is not reaching that line.

On top of that, you have placed `await bot.process_commands(message)` inside the `else` statement, which ignores the processing of the commands on the rest of the code.

Correct code should look something like this:

```py
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message): 
        print(message.author.id)
        if message.author.id == <user_id>:
            await message.add_reaction("❤️")
        else:  
            return
        await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: i tried that but it still just adds the reaction and the commands don't work. I deleted the block of code then the commands started working again so there is some error in the code...

Comment: Try deleting the `else` statement, that `return` on an event might be breaking your code. And to be honest it is not necessary at all.

Comment: i tired it..still no luck

Comment: is there something i have to import maybe?

Comment: Pretty sure if you don't get any error it is not a lack of imports. Could you modify your post and show us the full code you have on your `on_message` function?

Comment: Okay I just noticed you have put `await bot.process_commands(message)` but your bot is named `client`. The call shall be `client.process_commands(message)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `await bot.process_commands(message)` needs to be `client.process_commands(message)` because that's what you defined your bot instance as in `client = commands.Bot()`.